# donetbrowser HOWTO get posted form data from a Dotnetbrowser?

Tags: c#, html, post, postdata, dotnetbrowser

I need help to get posted form data a Dotnetbrowser. 
In fact, I want to add a listener event on a button, when this button is clicked, so I get the data, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <h1>Hello!!!</h1><br>
    <form
      id="formTrying"
      method="post"
      action="http://localhost/MyWebSite/MyMvcView?MyQueryStringParam1=something&Param2=something"
    >
      <input name="txtSomething" type="text" value="Trying something..."><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit...">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on submit button, I get the value from "txtSomething".
Or when the dotnetbrowser detect form submit, I get the value from "txtSomething".

Thanks in advance. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try registering an `OnClick` event listener for the corresponding DOM element to be notified about the clicks.

In your case, this can be done as shown below:

```
browser.FinishLoadingFrameEvent += delegate (object sender, FinishLoadingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsMainFrame)
    {
        DOMDocument document = e.Browser.GetDocument();
        List<DOMNode> inputNodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        DOMInputElement submitElement = (DOMInputElement)inputNodes.LastOrDefault();

        DOMEventHandler domEvent = delegate (object s, DOMEventArgs args)
        {
            //Obtain the value of the txtSomething field
            DOMInputElement txtSomethingElement = (DOMInputElement)document.GetElementByName("txtSomething");
            string value = txtSomethingElement.Value;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("txtSomething value = " + value);
        };

        submitElement.AddEventListener(DOMEventType.OnClick, domEvent, false);
    }
};
browser.LoadHTML(@"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello!!!</h1><br>
    <form
      id='formTrying'
      method='post'
      action='http://localhost/MyWebSite/MyMvcView?MyQueryStringParam1=something&Param2=something'
    >
      <input name='txtSomething' type='text' value='Trying something...'><br>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit...'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>");
```

The following article explains in details how to register a DOM event listener:
https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110034-listening-to-dom-events

Also, there is an article that shows how to set the values of the form fields programmatically: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110038-setting-input-field-value-working-with-form
. The `Value` and `Checked` properties in the sample are read-write properties that correspond to the `value` and `checked` properties available in JavaScript.

Comment: The point is, the value of INPUT was set for value="Trying something...", when I use this, I have the original value, not the updated value, the initial value is only for information purpose, but is not this value what I want. If a user insert another value, what I expect, I can't grab this information, only the initial value.

Comment: Are you using `GetAttribute("value")` to obtain the value? In this case, you need to use the `DOMFormControlElement.Value` property instead. The difference between attributes and properties is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: ThankYou, this is exactly what I want.